# How to change ORACLE ADR storing path?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

There is a server where the DB is installed. My system is communicating with DB and ADR structure has been created on my machine side. I know that the path was previously changed by one of admins. I was trying with adrci but i dont really know how does setting paths works. In adrci it looks to me like im setting path where diagnostic is stored and then it can be analyzed by the interpreter but i need to change the place where all stuff is being saved. Its all about changing path on application side, not on DB side(if it isnt needed). Any description about how does it work remotely would be very useful.

I was trying to find the solution in oracle documentation. I understodd some points but there is a lack in my knowledge of DB administration.

Comment: What do you mean by "where all stuff is being saved" - what stuff? ADR is for diagnostics; what else are you trying to use it for? And "ADR structure has been created on my machine side" sounds like you're trying to do something at the client end, where your application is running, not at the server end where the DB sits. [This article may be helpful](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/automatic-diagnostics-repository-11gr1#setting-adr-location) if the docs aren't. What are you trying to do in your application, and how has that led to wanting to change the ADR config?

Comment: Yes, the ADR is on the client machine(production server). It is collecting Diagnostic from DB which is installed on another server. The ADR Base path has been changed and I need to set it back to default. I dont really understand how does it work when ADR structure is created at client side. Should paths be configured on DB server side? Probably not. I would be very thankfull if you could describe me it.